# DevOps IIS Release Pipeline Not Extracting Files To Correct Location

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to setup a Release Pipeline for an ASPNET Core application to an on-premises IIS Virtual Machine (VM).

Everything is working as expected except when it deploys the files to the IIS server, but it's not extracting the files and it's dropping the zip file in the wrong folder location. For example, the application files are supposed to be deployed to `%SystemDrive%\sites\{mysite}` - This is setup in the Release Pipeline under the IIS Web App Manage section (shown below).

[image]

On the server, this is deploying to the correct location, but instead of all the app files being deployed to the `\sites\{mysite}` it's creating two additional folders  and then dropping a zip file called "WebApp.zip" like this, (`%SystemDrive%\sites\{mysite}\{artifactName}\{artifactName}\WebApp.zip`)

How do I get this to actually only deploy the website app files to the `\sites\{mysite}` directory?

I do have a yaml file, shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)' 

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: '{artifactName}' #removed the name for this post

- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '{removed}' #removed the name for this post
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    XmlVariableSubstitution: True
```

EDIT:

I've updated my yaml to look like what's shown below. If I do not include the `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task then no files ever get copied to the IIS server. This is also deploying now to a folder structure like this: `{artifact}\{artifact}\(all of the files)` which is an improvement, but still I don't need the two `{artifact}` folders, I just want the files deployed in the website's root directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've spent a pretty ridiculous amount of time on this thus far.

Updated Yaml:

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/Release/net5.0
    artifact: {artifactName}
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the path to the `*.zip` package file for your `IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0` task's `Package` input instead of just the default working directory.

Edit:

You have a lot going on that's confusing me and I believe it's probably because you're not sure what you're doing - forgive me if incorrect.  First, you look like you're building and packaging the build results twice - with `VSBuild@1` the first time, then using `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` the second time via two `DotNetCoreCLI@2` tasks.  You then have a `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` referencing the target of both packaging/publishing tasks.

You then attempt to deploy these packages but reference a completely different path/file.  Typically a build and deployment would be split into two separate jobs and the deployment job would download the published pipeline artifact.  That downloaded artifact is the path/file you want to reference in your deployment task's `Package` input.

Comment: I tried this, I also tried to put the full path like below, but it still doesn't work.
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '{mysite}'
    Package: 'c:\sites\{mysite}\{artifact}\{artifact}\WebApp.zip'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    XmlVariableSubstitution: True

Comment: Too long for a comment, I'll update my answer

Comment: You're not wrong about not knowing what I'm doing. Every time I've tried to setup a pipeline in DevOps it's never really worked, so I've always bagged it and tried again later. I'll work through your comment and see if it makes a difference. I appreciate it!

Comment: I've edited my original post with an updated yaml and some additional information. Does this look better?

Comment: Your updated YAML does not publish/package the result of the build.  I'd add the `dotnet publish` command task back to generate a zip file to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, then execute the `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task using that same directory (without the extra paths).  Next, create a second job that downloads the task and does the deployment looking for `*.zip` - many examples in Microsoft's documentation